# Firebase Exception while retrieving model that implements ClusterItem

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a model like this one:

```
class MyItem implements ClusterItem {

   private LatLng mPosition;
   private String mTitle;

   public MyItem(){
   }

   @Override
   public LatLng getPosition() {
      return mPosition;
   }

   .
   .
   .

}
```

I am able to push the items to Firebase, but whenever I try to retrieve them I get the following exception:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng is missing a constructor with no arguments.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? Does it mean that my Firebase model cannot implement ClusterItem?

Comment: *Does it mean that my Firebase model cannot implement ClusterItem?* no, it means that `Class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng is missing a constructor with no arguments.` ... so, serializer has problem to create model instance ... obvious solution is do not use `com.googl...LatLng` in model class but make own LatLng implementation or use simepl double for lat and lng

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution than a double for lat and lng but I guess I will go with that. Cheers.

Comment: So now my getPosition looks like this:

   `code`@Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    }

Comment: @Selvin: sounds like an answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Good way to do is just create a java class which will store the lat long with an empty constructor and you can retrieve the same modal class. Something like this

```
public class MyLatLng {
private double lat;
private double lng;

public MyLatLng() {}

public MyLatLng(double lat, double lng) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
}
}
```

But if you're intent on using a DataSnapshot, you can override FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot to handle the "UR Object":